# Debug Multiple ASP.NET Core Projects in VS 2017 and IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

I have spent two days trying to get this setup to work but apparently I haven't stumbled across the correct combination of settings yet.  From what I can tell this should be possible but I just can't get it to work.

I have 2 ASP.NET Core 2.2 projects.  One is a basic web server serving static resources and the other a Web API project handling standard REST requests.  Pretty standard stuff.  Just for reference I will soon need to add another API project as well but for now I just want to get this "simple" case working.

In the solution properties I have told VS to start both projects.

[image: solution properties]

I have also edited the `applicationhost.config` file to include both as a virtual directory in IIS Express.  I want anything with `/api` to go to the API controller project and everything else to go to the UI (static resource) project.

```
<site name="Par.Web" id="2">
<application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Source\repos\Par.Web\Par.Web.Ui" />
</application>
<application path="/api" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Source\repos\Par.Web\Par.Web.Api" />
</application>
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:57730:localhost" />
</bindings>
</site>
```

I also edited the `launchSettings.json` file of each project to include the same URL in `iisSettings`.

From the UI project:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57730/",
    "sslPort": 0
  }
```

},

And from the API project:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57730/api/",
    "sslPort": 0
  }
```

},

When I run the solution I get responses from the UI project but any API requests return a 404 error.  It seems as if VS isn't starting the second project because I also don't see anything in the output window from the API project.  However IIS Express seems to indicate everything is running.

[image: iis applications]

I have seen posts saying the ports between `applicationhost` and `launchSettings` must all be different but that didn't help.  In fact it seems IIS Express will rewrite the binding information in `applicationhost` to include the port number from `launchSettings` if they don't match.  I also tried making the API virtual directory a child element of the application in `applicationhost` but that didn't work either.  I have also made other desperate attempts to get it to *something*, such as running the projects out-of-process and creating a separate site in `applicationhost`, but all I manage to do is make things worse.

As I said, I've seen to other posts about doing this but everything I have found is for older versions of Visual Studio (or for Visual Studio Code) or the projects aren't .Net Core.  Apparently these make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Responses to similar questions:
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396337/running-multiple-apps-under-same-host-and-port
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513390/how-to-setup-multiple-apps-with-same-port-and-domain-but-different-paths-in-iise

Answer (score -2):

IIS Express is really not designed or intended to run one project as a virtual application to another: that's more of an advanced hosting scenario relegated to full IIS. That's not to say you can't achieve it, but it's going to be a lot of work and effort to get there, if you can.

However, I would question why you're doing this at all. The entire point of having separate apps is to make them independent of each other. If you're going to intrinsically bind the API to the web app like this, you might as well just have everything in one project. The same ASP.NET Core project can support both API endpoints and more traditional web endpoints (MVC/Razor Pages).

If you do want separate projects, then I would actually suggest using containers with orchestration, as that will make your development life far easier *and* have your applications ready for advanced deployment scenarios out of the box. You can still choose to do traditional IIS site deployment, in the end, if that's what you choose, but you can also then easily opt to run in the cloud or an on-prem cluster as well. All you need to do is install Docker for Windows. The container tooling in VS is actually quite good, and makes it easy to get going, even if you're brand new to the concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  You're right, these could be a single app (other than the UI/API separation of concerns).  But I will soon need to add another API project that is shared by my web app as well as a mobile app maintained by another developer.  So I will eventually need to figure this out anyway,  As for containers - that was how this was originally architected but  the powers-that-be shot that down.

Comment: Like I said in my answer. Using containers locally in development does not dictate a particular deployment strategy. You can still deploy however and wherever you like. You can use containers for you, and still do web deploys or whatever to IIS. Totally doable. Then, if you can finally convince management to go to a containerized deployment, you're already ahead of the game.